# Controlling USB input

Tags: .net

I need a method to delay input of a USB port during unassisted computer startup. My weather station data is a continious line feed, and when the computer restarts due to power failure, ETC, the computer sees the input and thinks the port is a "Track Ball" pointing device which locks the computer up displaying random pointers over entire screen.

Any one having any idea about this??

Fred

Answer (score 0):

Is the USB Device set in the BIOS to attempt to boot from?  You can adjust the boot sequence from within your BIOS settings.

Comment: No, normal boot up. Will take a look see.